# Android-jQuery cannot detect when popup dialog is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, android-webview

I have an Android app that is interfacing with a website (that I have no control of) and I'm able to do that by loading different Javascript or jQuery scripts to my WebView. One of my tasks is for my app to detect when a dialog in the website is displayed and closed. So far I've been able to detect if the dialog has been displayed through this script (works for both Desktop and Mobile mode):

```
$(".ui-link").click(function() {
     Android.dialogOpened(); // function in my Android app 
});
```

And detect if the dialog was closed by pressing the X button of the dialog through this script (works for both Desktop and Mobile mode):

```
$(".ui-btn-left.ui-btn.ui-shadow.ui-btn-corner-all.ui-btn-icon-notext.ui-btn-up-f").on("tap", function() {
     Android.xBtnClicked();
});
```

By messing around with the Console in my PC (Desktop mode only), I've also been able to detect when the dialog is closed by clicking outside the dialog.

```
// popupDialog-screen is the ID of the space outside the dialog
$("#popupDialog-screen").click(function(){
     alert('clicked outside'); // or the Android function
});
```

But when I try to use my mobile device (or by changing to Mobile mode in the Console), the script above does not work! I've also tried using various other scripts using different classes or divs, also tried using .on('tap') instead of click, and many other methods, but none of them have worked so far .

This is my first time ever using Javascript and jQuery so I don't understand much of the code of the website. If it helps, I saw that it uses Tapestry, and I saw the code to display the popup, but did not see where it is closed. Below is the code I found (I did not make this):

```
// dialoglink.js
(function( $ ) {
    T5.extendInitializers(function(){
        var bindElements = [];
        function init(spec) {
            var elementId = specs.triggerId;
            if ( $.inArray(elementId, bindElements) === -1 ) {
                bindElements.push(elementId);
                $('#' + elementId).click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    jQuery('#' + spec.dialogId).popup('open');
                    return false;
                });
            }
        }
        return {
            dialogLink : init
        };
    });
}) ( jQuery );
```

What do you think is the problem? I've been at this for hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work!

Searched about popups in jQuery mobile and used the afterclose event.
Here is the working script:

```
$('#popupDialog').popup({
  afterclose: function( event, ui ) {alert('CLOSED')}
});
```

Source: http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#event-afterclose